# Numbering a text within the parallel environment

Tags: numbering, memoir, parallel

I'm using a special class required by my university {ulthèse}, but it is based on the `memoir` class, so my MWE should be relevant. I want to number a latin text that I have put in the `parallel` package environment. The `lineno` package seems to be the best at doing that, but I have tried the different solutions proposed in other similar questions, like putting `\requirepackage{lineno}` before the document class and nothing seems to work. Either it splits the lines of the text on different pages, either it does nothing. I have also tried to number the text with the verse environment and it does not work either.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}[p]{13.5cm}{13.5cm}
\ParallelLText{
\begin{linenumbers}
\lipsum[1]
\end{linenumbers}}
\ParallelRText{\lipsum[1]}  
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}[1]{2}
\begin{linenumbers}
\sloppy\lipsum[1]
\end{linenumbers}
\switchcolumn
\begin{linenumbers}
\sloppy\lipsum[1]
\end{linenumbers}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be perfect, but I'm using the parallel package because it enables me to print parallel text on two pages. I think this package only creates two columns ? Thank you for your answer and your time.

Comment: Ah, you WANTED two pages.  That can be done.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much! I spent hours trying to make it work!

Comment: Parallel hasn't been updated since 2003.